# URL not Redirecting with Internet Explorer

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, url, redirect, http-status-code-404

ok so i have a .htaccess file for redirecting people

if the webpage doesn't exist, i want it to go to /notfound.php
It works fine in EVERY browser except internet explorer...

can anyone help.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RedirectMatch ^/$ /notfound.php
DirectoryIndex /notfound.php

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

Ive tried all solutions, making it bigger than 1kb, loads of things, i cant make IE redirect to /notfound, it just displays the typical 404 Not Found page...

Comment: You are sure your `notfound.php` file is bigger than 1kb? You might need to try a hard refresh.

Comment: notfound.php is 11kb, there must be a proper reason, it works in every browser but IE

Comment: Your code works for me when I try it on IE. Did you try clearing your cache and trying again?

Comment: Yes, i've tried clearing the cache. Ive tried it on 2 computers with Internet Explorer on it.

Comment: Have you tries removing all but the first and last line of the code?